# In Rails 6, how do I allow deveopment console access from any local machine/network?

Tags: docker, console, ruby-on-rails-6, web-console

I’m running a Rails 6 application from a Docker container.  When I start my application, I get errors like this on the log

```
rails.1      | Cannot render console from 142.29.0.1! Allowed networks: 0.0.0.0, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255, ::1
```

How do I allow connections from any network?  I don’t want to hard-code IPs because that won’t scale to other developers machines.  I tried adding this in config/environments/development.rb

```
  config.web_console.permissions = '0.0.0.0/255.255.255.255'
```

But after restarting my server I get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that `'0.0.0.0/255.255.255.255'` is not correct syntax - especially network part after `/`. Valid [CIDR notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing#CIDR_notation) should be use there.

If you want to allow all IPv4 IPs, then correct CIDR notation is:

```
config.web_console.permissions = '0.0.0.0/0'
```

See: [AWS: What does 0.0.0.0/0 and ::/0 mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44234374/aws-what-does-0-0-0-0-0-and-0-mean)

If you want to allow all local IPv4 IPs, then you need to know right CIDR notation of your local network, e.g.`192.168.0.0/16`:

```
config.web_console.permissions = '192.168.0.0/16'
```

See also rail doc https://github.com/rails/web-console#configweb_consolepermissions

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ngrok, you can enable all IPv6 networks using

```
config.web_console.permissions = '::/0'
```